# Apache FTPClient upload jar files ends up being corrupt

Tags: java, ftp-client, corrupt

I seem to be uploading corrupt jar files to a remote server using Apache's FTPClient 3.0.1. I am also setting the file and file transfer type to binary.

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("filename");
ftp.setFileTransferMode(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.storeFile(fis);
fis.close();
ftp.logout();
ftp.disconnect();
```

any help would be appreciated!

Jason

Comment: do text files get transferred correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to try:

Are you absolutely 100% positive that:

a) storeFile() is returning true
b) you aren't throwing an exception somewhere

if you step through it in a debugger does it complete each call in your routine, and the file still winds up as partial on the ftp server?

What part of the file isn't getting to the ftp server?  Create a test file that contains bytes 0-255 repeated 5 or 10 times, then try uploading that.  Then download the result and see what's getting killed.

Comment: The file is getting to the server. I am sure of that, but it just ends up being corrupted. The size uploaded is also a little bit bigger which is strange.

Comment: and when you open the files and compare them byte by byte, what is the result?  In other words, characterize the corruption.

Answer (score 5):

I've got the same problem, problem was resolved using setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE) :

```
client.connect(this.HOST);
client.login(USER, PASSWORD);
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, in my case solution was using `client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);` **after login, not before.**